# How to use CFLDAP without a hard-coded password

Tags: coldfusion, ldap

I am using CFLDAP in a ColdFusion application.

Currently, the SERVER, USERNAME, and PASSWORD are hard-coded in the application.cfc as application scope variables.

```
<cfscript>
    application.ldapserver = "servername";'
    application.ldapuser = "username";'
    application.ldappwd = "password";'
</cfscript>
```

Later in my code, I am using CFLDAP:

```
<CFLDAP ="GetLDAPinfo" action="query" 
        server = "#application.ldapserver#"
        username = "#application.ldapuser#"
        password = "#application.password#"
        ....
</CFLDAP>
```

How can I get around using a hard-coded username and password ?

I was hoping to find something to configure in the ColdFusion Administrator similar to how e-mail is set up, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea if this will work, but you could set the variables in an encrypted file and include that file in your Application.cfc.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are commonly used for storing credentials on a server. Maybe this article will help: [Reading Environment Variables In ColdFusion](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2838-reading-environment-variables-in-coldfusion.htm)

Comment: That isn't a bad idea, but the primary point is that the username and password shouldn't be accessible anywhere as plain text.  In the environment variables, they would still be accessible as plain text.

Comment: You could encrypt it and then decrypt it after you get it. If your goal is to remove the password from your codebase, environment variables are a common place to store them.

Answer (score 0):

Using the environment variables approach with plain text files is an accepted practice. You don't store that file in source control, but manage the per-environment settings in a secure location.

Local devs get local credentials (ideally unique per developer), but they don't see credentials for higher environments. Those should only be accessible by the appropriate users.

Here's an example of [using .env files with NodeJS](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-node-environment-variables-with-a-dotenv-file-for-node-js-and-npm/).

Alternatively, you could store the credentials in the database and retrieve them on application start. But even then, do the local developers have access to that environment's database? And you can always dump the application scope to view the values. Or you could use something like [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/), but I don't know how well that works with non-AWS systems.

Since the current credentials are hardcoded, they'll always be in source control history. Make sure

1. you're rotating those credentials as part of this effort
2. creating credentials per environment
3. rotating them all on a regular basis

Comment: I appreciate your response.  My employer, however, wants to do everything possible to avoid having the username and password accessible, even if it is an accepted practice.

Comment: @RickInWestPalmBeach I get it. I used a database approach to load credentials and not the environment file approach. This was at a financial services company and worked for our 3rd party security audits.

Comment: If you don't want these values to be accessible you'll have to take them out of the application scope since those variables are visible if debugging is turned on.

Comment: Debugging is definitely not turned on, but thank you.